# Knockout: HTML-binding in text-binding

Tags: html, knockout.js

Depending on the outcome of an expression in my `text data-binding`,
I would like to display a property or some HTML code.

This is the expression:

```
resultsCount().length > 0 ? resultsCount().length : {html: loadingIcon}
```

And it's being used in the following context:

```
<span data-bind="text: resultsCount().length > 0 ? resultsCount().length : {html: loadingIcon}"></span></strong></p>
```

This obviously doesn't work (because of `{html: loadingIcon}`), but I'd like to know how I can make this work. 
The `loadingIcon` HTML is a simple HTML structure like this:

```
self.loadingIcon = "<div class='loadingIconWrapper'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'></i></div>";
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use just html binding to achieve result.

```
<span data-bind="html: resultsCount().length > 0 ? resultsCount().length :loadingIcon"></span>
```

[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/31e7vdgo)

Or if you don't want to use html binding for displaying number then use if binding.

```
<!-- ko if: resultsCount().length> 0 --> 
   <span data-bind="text:resultsCount().length"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: resultsCount().length> 0 --> 
   <span data-bind="html:loadingIcon"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/31e7vdgo/1/)

Comment: Simple, yet effective. Thank you!